# ANTLR4 flutter to access each widget in BuildVisitor

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, widget, antlr4

Edited

I'm trying to use ANTLR with flutter and I'm facing some diffcuilties trying to determine which functions in the Dart2Buildvisitor can access the UI widgets. I want to access each widget separately (example: a function for alertdialog, a function for textfield) but as I'm still new to this, I can't seem to know where to find them. Is there a way I can individually access each widget?

Edit 2: When I parse a flutter code to see where the widgets lie in the parse tree, it lies under primary and identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty much Dart all the way down.  Very comprehensive architecture guide at https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/architectural-overview.   The widgets are mostly in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets

Answer (score 0):

Flutter widgets are often expressed just as object literals in dart. Look for the return result of the build function of any Flutter widget.
Furthermore, flutter widgets are much smaller and more granular than widgets are traditionally defined.

So in many languages you might have a widget with 20 properties but in flutter that might be implemented by a nested tree of small simple widgets such as centre, border, text etc.